# Javascript all unique options of array of elements and number of options

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, filter, combinations

## Problem 1

I have this variables

```
var myArr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];
var nOptions = 10;
```

and I'm trying to get all unique possible combination with 10 options.

Results example:

```
var result1 = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"];
var result2 = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B"];
var result3 = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A"];
var result4 = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A"];
----------------------------------------------------------------
var result5 = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"];
var result6 = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B"];
var result7 = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B"];
----------------------------------------------------------------
var result8 =  ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B"];
var result9 =  ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B"];
var result10 = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "B"];
----------------------------------------------------------------
var result11 = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B"];
var result12 = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "B"];
var result13 = ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B"];
----------------------------------------------------------------
var resultn = ["I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I"];
```

1. Is there any way to print all that results in JavaScript?
2. Is there a math formula so I can know the number of all combinations without making all the loops?

## Problem 2

Finally I want to make a filter so I can have all possible combinations with the new filters.
Example:

```
var minA = 0;
var maxA = 3;

var minB = 2;
var maxB = 4;

var minC = 0;
var maxC = 3;

-------------

var minI = 3;
var maxI = 5;
```

Example valid results with filter:

```
var result1 = ["B", "B", "B", "B", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "A"];
var result2 = ["B", "B", "B", "B", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "C"];
var result3 = ["B", "B", "B", "B", "I", "I", "I", "I", "A", "A"];
```

1. Is there any way to print all filter results in JavaScript directly or I have to loop throw all results and make counters for each letter and then if all counters are valid with the filter options print the new results?
2. Is there a math formula so I can know the number of all combinations with filters without making all the loops?

Thanks to everybody who can help in making the code. I will update the code so everybody can use it for future projects.

## CODE Problem 1

```
var myArr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];
var nOptions = 10;

myCounter = 0;
allResults = [];

for (let a = 0; a < 9; a++) {
    for (let b = 0; b < 9; b++) {
      for (let c = 0; c < 9; c++) {
        for (let d = 0; d < 9; d++) {
          for (let e = 0; e < 9; e++) {
            for (let f = 0; f < 9; f++) {
              for (let g = 0; g < 9; g++) {
                for (let h = 0; h < 9; h++) {
                  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                        allResults.push([myArr[a], myArr[b], myArr[c], myArr[d], myArr[e], myArr[f], myArr[g], myArr[h], myArr[i], myArr[j]]);
                        myCounter++;
                    }
                    //break;
                  }
                  //break;
                }
                //break;
              }
              //break;
            }
            //break;
          }
          //break;
        }
        //break;
      }
      //break;
    }
    //break;
  }
```

## Better CODE Problem 1

I made a better code so now nOptions can be a reasonable number (min 0, max 26) but a number too big will have too much possible combinations and the pc couldn't process all that data. A maxium reasonable number would be nOptions = 6. That means 9^6 = 531.441 results.

```
var myArr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];
var nOptions = 2;

var myCounter = 0;
var allResults = [];
var myLetters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];


codeLine='';

for (let i = 0; i < nOptions; i++) {
codeLine += 'for (let ' + myLetters[i] + ' = 0; ' + myLetters[i] + ' < 9; ' + myLetters[i] + '++) {';
}

codeLine += 'allResults.push([';
for (let i = 0; i < nOptions; i++) {
  codeLine += 'myArr[' + myLetters[i] + ']';
  if (i !== nOptions - 1) {
    codeLine += ', ';
  }
}
codeLine += ']);';

codeLine += 'myCounter++;';
//codeLine += 'console.log(myCounter);';

for (let i = 0; i < nOptions; i++) {
    codeLine += '}';
}

//console.log(codeLine);
eval(codeLine);

console.table(allResults);
```

Comment: The math formula is `10^10`, or 10 billion combinations.

Comment: I am really intrigued to understand why are you doing this or what are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: @AlonEitan, I missed the copy paste code. I updated the question with the code I tried.

Comment: @Pointy after a few tests of my code I can see that the numer of unique combinations are 9^nOptions. In first scenario would be 9^10. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Daniel yes, correct, I miscounted the array length.

Comment: The formula is the number of symbols to the power of the size of your array, so 9^10 is correct.

Comment: Trivia : If you printed your result on paper, one per line, 66 lines per page, it would produce a stack of paper roughly 3.4 miles high.

Comment: @phatfingers, you are not the only one in the audience who was musing about that. I was thinking in terms of number of trees. Note that in a high wind there might be stability problems with your tower.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert between numbers and letters by their digit. Here you have 9 letters you care about, so using base 9 we have: 0=a, 1=b, ... 8=i.

Then use toString to convert all the integers from 0 to 9^11-1 to base 9, with leading 0s. Finally, convert the digits back to the appropriate letters.

```
0 -> 0000000000 -> aaaaaaaaaa
1 -> 0000000001 -> aaaaaaaaab
...
64340123 -> 0064340123 -> aagedeabcd
...
8888888888 -> 8888888888 -> iiiiiiiiii
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think of this recursively, it becomes fairly simple to write the code that generates these combinations.  Simply take each letter in turn as the first letter, then recursively calculate all the words one character shorter for the remainder and combine them.  We bottom out with a result holding just one empty array when the count is `0`.  Here's a simple version of the code:

```js
const makeWords = (cs, n) =>
  n == 0
    ? [[]]
    : cs .flatMap (c => makeWords (cs, n - 1) .map (w => [c, ...w]))

const letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

console .log (makeWords (letters, 3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

As others have pointed out the formula for the count of such words is simply `(number of letters) ^ (word length)`.  So for my example of three-letter words on a four-character alphabet, there are `4 ^ 3`, or `64` results.  For ten-letter words on a nine-character alphabet, there are `9 ^ 10` or `3486784401` results.  I hope you're not planning on printing them all, or even logging them all to the console!

Answer (score 0):

## Solution to problem 1#

```
var myArr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];
var nOptions = 2;

var myCounter = 0;
var allResults = [];
var myLetters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];


codeLine='';

for (let i = 0; i < nOptions; i++) {
codeLine += 'for (let ' + myLetters[i] + ' = 0; ' + myLetters[i] + ' < 9; ' + myLetters[i] + '++) {';
}

codeLine += 'allResults.push([';
for (let i = 0; i < nOptions; i++) {
  codeLine += 'myArr[' + myLetters[i] + ']';
  if (i !== nOptions - 1) {
    codeLine += ', ';
  }
}
codeLine += ']);';

codeLine += 'myCounter++;';
//codeLine += 'console.log(myCounter);';

for (let i = 0; i < nOptions; i++) {
    codeLine += '}';
}

//console.log(codeLine);
eval(codeLine);

console.table(allResults);
```

Comment: This is not an answer.